# Помочь с написанием запроса Linq2sql left join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq2sql

Как написать запрос, который вернет несколько (2-3) топовых (лучших навыков) для каждого соискателя? Есть таблицы:

Соискатель:

```
public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CurrentSkill> CurrentSkills { get; set; }   

    public Applicant()
    { 
        CurrentSkills = new List<CurrentSkill>(); 
    }
}
```

оценка

```
 public class Rate
 {
    public Rate()
    {
        this.CurrentSkills = new HashSet<CurrentSkill>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public int RateItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CurrentSkill> CurrentSkills { get; set; }   
}
```

Навык:

```
 public class Skill
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Есть таблица связка для организации связи многие - ко - многим

```
public class CurrentSkill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SkillId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RateId { get; set; }

    public virtual Rate Rates { get; set; }
    public virtual Skill Skills { get; set; }

    public int? ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}
```

сейчас я получаю данные следующим образом

```
   var applicantArray = (from i in  db.Applicants
                              .Include("CurrentSkills")   
                               select i  ).ToArray();

    // вспомагательный класс для отображения на экране             
         List<ApplicantViewModel> applModel = new List<ApplicantViewModel>();

        foreach (var applicantItem in applicantArray)
        {
            ApplicantViewModel appl = new ApplicantViewModel();
            StringBuilder topSkillName = new StringBuilder();  

            if (applicantItem.CurrentSkills.Count() > 0)
            {
                var skills = applicantItem.CurrentSkills.OrderByDescending(i => i.Rates.RateItem).Take(3);

                foreach (var skill in skills)
                {
                    topSkillName.Append(skill.Skills.Name); 
                    topSkillName.Append("/");                           
                }

            }

            appl.Id = applicantItem.ApplicantId;
            appl.AddedDate = applicantItem.AddedDate;            
            appl.FName = applicantItem.Name.FirstName;            

            appl.Skills = topSkillName.ToString();
            applModel.Add(appl);
        }
```

как можно получить эти данные одним запросом ?

Comment: несколько это сколько?

Comment: первые 3 навыка

Comment: что-нибудь пробовали сами?

Comment: да, но поскольку используется связь типа ноль - ко многим - дальше левостороннего соединения не знаю что делать.

Comment: добавьте ваш код попытки

Comment: var res = (from a in db.Applicants
                       join c in db.CurrentSkills on a.ApplicantId equals           c.ApplicantId into temp
                       from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new CurrentSkill() { RateId  = 0, SkillId = 0}) 
                       select
                     new
                     {
                         id = t.ApplicantId,
                         rate = t.RateId ,
                         skill = (t.Rates.RateItem)
                     }
                      ).ToArray();

Comment: добавьте этот код, также в вопрос

Comment: Добавьте код ваших попыток в вопрос

Comment: Добавил работоспособный

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть ощущение, что ваши модели неполные, в них не хватает определенных свойств, но итог будет примерно следующим:

```
List<ApplicantViewModel> applModel = db.Applicants.Select(x => new ApplicantViewModel
    {
        Id = x.ApplicantId,
        FName = x.Name, //Не нашел свойства в выложенной вами модели
        AddedDate = x.BirthDate, //Не нашел свойства в выложенной вами модели
        Skills = String.Join("/"
                , x.CurrentSkills
                    .OrderByDescending(y => y.Rates.RateItem)
                    .Take(3)
                    .Select(y => y.Skills.Name))
    }).ToList();
```

Как Вы видите, я просто воспользовался методом `String.Join()` для того, чтобы сделать из списка строку с разделителями.

Comment: А что, `String.Join` в таком контексте будет работать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov меня тоже терзают смутные сомнения, вот если предварительно *вытянуть*, т.е. материализовать коллекцию, то легко